# How to write unique CSV file names in R

Tags: r, csv

I conducted 12 different experiments and 
I want to apply a script to each csv file in the folder.
The csv files in the folder have names like
emo_1, emo_2. etcetera

After conducting analysis, joining with other files of type
route_1, route_2...etc

I wish to write.csv and assign unique names, so I get unique files in my directory of type
emoroute_1, emoroute_2

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you have samples 1 to `n`, just do:

```
fileNames <- paste0("emoroute_", 1:n)
```